# Android accountmanager and storing passwords

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

I was reading around other threads but cant arrive at a proper answer. So here it goes:

Imagine that I have a Oauth2 server implementation securing the backend APIs. I would want my app to function like facebook or gmail app and would want to stay authenticated forever (till they manually revoke) after they initially sign-in. They should never be asked their password again. Is this possible without storing the password on the device?

Are refresh tokens there to solve this problem or should this the approached in some other way? Also is there a android library that solves this problem since I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

You can save username, password, and token for your user via `AccountManager` and retrieve it later. Just check if the user account exists or not when the app opens to act accordingly.

You can also update the account credentials later on.
A basic example snippet is below

```
private static final String TYPE_ACCOUNT = "com.some.package";    

public static void addAccount(Context context, String username, String password, String token) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account account = new Account(username, TYPE_ACCOUNT);
    accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);
    accountManager.setAuthToken(account, TYPE_ACCOUNT, token);
  }

 public static Account getUserAccount(Context context) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account account = null;

    try {
      account = accountManager.getAccountsByType(TYPE_ACCOUNT)[0];
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }
    return account;
  }
```

Comment: Is this the best practice? Rather than finding some code I'm more interested in how exactly its implemented by major apps like gmail or fb for example.

Comment: To use AccountManager is best practice since it provides secure, readable and maintainable code. In your case, you can use it and just check user's token via the AccountManager. Implementing add, remove and revoke operations are pretty basic, There are not much open source projects of Google that use AccountManager it seems. Just found this https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/e8c61e7e23f74aa6786696dad22e5136b423a334/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/sync/account/Account.java

Comment: Using the AccountManager is indeed best practice. But would really like to know how other standard apps exactly do it. Like what do they store in AccountManager? Only the access token? Then how does it work after its expired?

Comment: To create an account, unique name and password is required whereas token is optional. At some point, if your token is invalidated, you need to call accountManager.invalidateAuthToken() and then acquire a new one according to your authentication flow.

Comment: @dgngulcan what could I do about the exception I get when running this code: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10076 cannot explicitly add accounts of type

Comment: What I've done in the past is encrypt the users password with the android.security.KeyChain; and store the encrypted password in the preferences, then you can decrypt when you need to refresh the authtoken.  However I find myself back here, as I'm looking for more of a refresh token implementation with firebase authentication

Comment: This throws a `SecurityException` - Are you missing anything else that the developer needs to do in your answer?

Comment: It's been a while, there may be some API changes.